# Calculate the surface integral of bounded cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $$\int\int z^2\,dS,$$ where $S$ is the part of outer surface of cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ between the planes $z=0$ and $z=3$.

The answer given in book is $\pi$ but I am not getting this answer.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.  If you edit your question to put in some of your working, we can help you find out where you have problems.

Answer (score 2):

Since your surface is a cylindar of radius $2$, the surface element can be written as $\mathrm{d}S=2\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}z$. Then your integral can be written as:
$$I=2\iint\limits_{(\theta,z)\in[0,2\pi]\times[0,3]}z^2\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}z,$$
and using separation of variables:
$$I=2\int\limits_{\theta\in[0,2\pi]}\mathrm{d}\theta\int\limits_{z\in[0,3]}z^2\mathrm{d}z=2\times2\pi\times\frac{3^3}3=36\pi.$$

---

The answer $\pi$ that you're given is certainly wrong for the following very simple reason: you're integrating a non-negative function on the cylinder; so the integral is non-less than the integral on the portion between $z=1$ and $z=3$; now, on this portion, $z^2\geq1$, hence the integral must be at least the surface area of the portion of the cylinder between $z=1$ and $z=3$ which is $2\times\pi\times2\times2=8\pi$.